# What is the webkitwebprocess in linux?

Tags: linux, process, browser, lightweight, webkit

So the other day I was looking for a ultra light weight browser. Midori was the first option as per internet. But this was the RAM usage of it.

[RAM USAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcznU.png)

though midori took only around 100MB, the webkitwebprocess ,which is being run only when I use midori, takes almost 1.2 GB of ram. what is this process ? And is there a way to run midori without this ? Also suggest some 'real' lightweight browsers unlike this.

Comment: Please do not add images or image links as far as possible. Better copy the output of your RAM usage using code formatting. See -> [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: As user FelixJN has already stated, please refrain from using images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebKitWebProcess` is part of the [Webkit](https://webkit.org/) (or possibly [WebkitGTK](https://webkitgtk.org/) for you as you are using Gnome) set, used for rendering homepages.

It is after all the websites that are so overloaded that the browser requires such loads - the browser may be as lightweight as you want, if the website is this resource-demanding, there is no chance. If you want to reduce this, use ad- and scriptblockers, deny autoplaying videos, etc.

Websites are annoyingly bloated these days.